# getting the lower value of the rating

Tags: sql

I asked a question on sql few hours ago and I made few changes.

The code won't look like a proper code because I am at a learning stage and basically need to type in everyline into this psql program on unix....

so, the following is my code

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(       custID INT PRIMARY KEY,
        customer_name VARCHAR(50),
        customer_address VARCHAR(200)
);

 CREATE TABLE product
(       prodID INT PRIMARY KEY,
        productName VARCHAR(40),
        productPrice NUMERIC(12, 2),
        productManufacturer VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE sale
(       saleID INT PRIMARY KEY,
        custID INT
        prodID INT
        saleQuantity INT,
        saleCost NUMERIC(5, 2),
        FOREIGN KEY (prodID) REFERENCES product,
        FOREIGN KEY(custID) REFERENCES customer
);

CREATE TABLE rating
(       prodID,
        custID,
        rating_date DATE PRIMARY KEY,
        rating_stars tinyint,
        FOREIGN KEY (prodID) REFERENCES product,
        FOREIGN KEY (custID) REFERENCES customer
);


SELECT productName
FROM product
WHERE productName = 'FFPXC Corp'
ORDER BY productPrice ASC;

SELECT DISTINCT productName
FROM product, rating
WHERE  product.prodID = rating.prodID AND ratingStars >= 3;

SELECT productName, SUM(saleQuantity) AS revenue
FROM product, sale
WHERE product.prodID = sale.prodID
GROUP BY productName;

SELECT product_name, round(avg(rating_stars), 1) AS avg_stars, MAX(rating_date) AS recent_date
WHERE product.prod_id = rating.prod_id
FROM product, rating
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER BY avg_stars DESC;
```

Now, I have one more question to do which is to see if a customer gave more than 1 rating on 1 product and if that is the case, get the lowest rating that the customer has given and return it with name of the product and the customer's name.

Problem is... I have no idea how to do it..
I am very new to sql and am still trying to get my head around my first programming language: java and turns out sql is VERY different from it..

it's not like I can use if statements and so as a last resort, I have decided to put the question up here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by more than one column, as well as use a group by with a statement that has a join.

```
 Select min(rating_stars), customer_name, ProductName
 From rating r
    Inner join customer c
       On c.custid = r.custid
    Inner join product p
       On p.prodid=r.prodid
Group by customer_name, ProductName
```

Ps, I recommend that you take a look at SqlFiddle.com for setting up your structure and data for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I have one more question. 
you introduced r and c in your code but I have no idea what they are :(
are they meant to be like objects?

Comment: @ymc331 they are abbreviations, so when it says `rating r` its means from now on the rating table is going to be referred to as just `r`

Comment: alright... thank you :) i thought you needed AS to do that but i guess that way is much easier.